# Docusaurus V2 - Activating Google Analytics hides navbar and footer

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, docusaurus

We want to implement Google Analytics into our online website, however when we add the code our menu and footer disappears.

According to documentation on the official website https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/using-plugins/#docusaurusplugin-google-analytics this can be achieved through updating the `docusaurus.config.js` and adding a plugin `@docusaurus/plugin-google-analytics` or by by adding to the present `@docusaurus/preset-classic`.

---

1. Installing as a plugin with the following code, hides our menu and footer (just vanishes). But Google Analytics does register the real-time traffic.

```
  themeConfig: {
    googleAnalytics: {
      trackingID: 'UA-GACODE-1',
      // Optional fields.
      anonymizeIP: true, // Should IPs be anonymized?
    },
  },
```

---

2. Trying to activate it through the existing `@docusaurus/present-clasic` doesn't process anything (Chrome inspector has no traffic to Google and AdBlock is not active)

```
presets: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        googleAnalytics: {
          trackingID: 'UA-GACODE-1',
        },
        docs: {
          sidebarPath: require.resolve('./sidebars.js')
        },
        theme: {
          customCss: require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css'),
        },
        highlight: { 
          theme: 'default',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
```

---

Has anyone activated Google Analytics successfully on Docusaurus V2?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Do I need to add the script code separately too? Apart from this? @Daniel

Comment: Hi, I don't believe you need any extra scripts. Just add Google Analytics code to the themeConfig as shown in my answer below. @Akhila

Comment: I actually created account in google analytics and have an id that starts with GA and not UA.. For some reason I'm not able to see any data in the account, and I have only added just this line.. Does it only work for UA code? @Daniel

Comment: Not sure about GA, would suggest trying it in production (not localhost) and confirm no adblock etc. They have an active docusaurus community if you need specific help: https://discord.com/invite/docusaurus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the accepted answer is no longer valid after this [PR](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/pull/5832). So both the `gtag` and `googleAnalytics` should go back into the `presets` configuration now.

```
// docusaurus.config.js

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        docs: /* ... */,
+       gtag: {
+         trackingID: 'xxx',
+       },
+       googleAnalytics: {
+         trackingID: 'xxx',
+       },
      },
    ],
  ],
  themeConfig: {
-   gtag: {
-     trackingID: 'xxx',
-   },
-   googleAnalytics: {
-     trackingID: 'xxx',
-   },
    // other options
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Google Analytics is no longer with this previous format, see accepted answer.

Ref: https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/pull/5832 - Thanks @seiwon-park

Comment: **THIS IS NO LONGER VALID** according to `[ERROR] Error: The "googleAnalytics" field in themeConfig should now be specified as option for plugin-google-analytics. For preset-classic, simply move themeConfig.googleAnalytics to preset options. More information at https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/pull/5832` So, insert it inside `preset`.